# Why I'm getting Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewResult' to type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ContentResult'?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, action-filter

I'm following this tutorial on Linkedin [Tutorial](https://www.linkedin.com/learning/l-essentiel-d-asp-dot-net-core-pour-dot-net-5/implementer-des-filtres-d-action?autoplay=true&contextUrn=urn%3Ali%3AlyndaLearningPath%3A57b467b33dd5598234d9059a&resume=false) , and in this video the presenter shows how to use ActionFilter , however , when I execute this application

> Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewResult' to type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ContentResult'

- ProductActionFilter

  ```
    public override void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        var result = (ContentResult)filterContext.Result; // Exception thrown here 
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream("c:\\logs\\log.txt", FileMode.Append))
        {
            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs))
            {
                sw.WriteLine("Résultat: " + result.Content);
            }
        }
    }
  ```

What is the reason of this?

Answer (score 1):

It's quite possible that the ActionFilter executes multiple times, and sometimes it may execute for situations that differ from what you are anticipating.

Try doing a check for the expected type, then only proceed if the type is found, which can be done as follows:

```
public override void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext filterContext)
{
    if (filterContext.Result is ContentResult cr) // ADDED: type check using pattern matching
    {
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream("c:\\logs\\log.txt", FileMode.Append))
        {
            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs))
            {
                sw.WriteLine("Résultat: " + cr.Content);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: yes, the exception is gone, But I would like to know why the cast wouldn't work, what's the correct implementation of the `OnREsultExecuted` method? Did I miss something ?

Comment: Yes, I've updated my comment.

Comment: You were doing a forced type cast, that by definition fails if the types are incompatible, and that's the case here for some of the cases where the ActionFilter was triggered. There is nothing wrong with doing a type check, in fact it is needed quite often.